# NavLink is not working at all, neither the URL changes nor the page renders

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to create SideNavBar component by keeping the routes in different file and dropdown in different file. When I am clicking at a NavLink Button nothing happens. I think the problem is with routes in App.jsx file but I am not able to figure out the solution to this problem. I am using a dashboard template for my project.

**Sidenav.jsx**

```
{routes.map(({ pages, layout }, key) => (
            <ul key={key} className="mb-4 flex flex-col gap-1">
              {pages.map(({ icon, name, path, submenu, outterpath }, index) => (
                (submenu.length > 0 ? (
                  <div key={index}>
                    {activeDropdown === index && (
                      <DropDown menus={submenu} layout={layout} outterpath={outterpath}/>
                    )}
                  </div>                                
                ):(<></>))
              ))}
            </ul>
          ))}
```

**DropDown.jsx**

```
        {menus.map((items, index) => (
          <li key={index} className="pb-4 hover:scale-105 duration-300">
            <button onClick={handleToggle}>{items.title}</button>
            {console.log(`/${layout}${outterpath}${items.path}`)}
            {active === index && (
                <li>
                    <NavLink to={`/${layout}${outterpath}${items.path}`}>
                      <button>{items.title}</button>
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            )}
          </li>
        ))

export default DropDown
```

**Dashboard.jsx**

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

        <Routes>
          {routes.map(
            ({ layout, pages }) =>
              layout === "dashboard" &&
              pages.map(({ path, element, submenu }) => (
                (submenu.length>0 ? (
                  (submenu.map((items, index) => (
                    <Routeexact key={index} path={items.path} element={element} />
                  )))
                ): (
                  <Route exact path={path} element={element} />
                ))
              ))
          )}
        </Routes>
```

My NavLinks in the Dropdown.jsx file is not working at all. When I click on the button under NavLink, nothing happens as if I never clicked it.

Comment: `path="/dashboard/*"` makes sense, it will match any `"/dashboard"` sub-route. `path="/dashboard/**/*"` is rather meaningless. What exactly is the problem? It's unclear from the code you shared, and it seems you left out the most important code, the `Dashboard` component. Is `Dashboard` rendering all those other components? Please [edit] to clarify the issue in better detail and to include a more complete [mcve].

Comment: I have added the Dashboard file too. I tried add the route by mapping the submenu there as well, but it doesn't seem to work. Dashboard is not rendering the submenu elements. When I am clicking on the NavLink, nothing happens.

Comment: you want to minimize the amount of code passed to us, just include a short code that reproduces the issue

Comment: I have tried to minimize the code as much as i can while retaining the necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by simply maping the submenu over the parent file only instead of creating a new dropdown component.

```
{activeDropdown === index && (
                  //<DropDown menus={submenu} layout={layout} outterpath={path}/>
                  <div className="flex text-white text-medium pt-4 justify-start gap-4 pl-4 capitalize text-left" >
                    <ul>
                      {submenu.map((items, index) => (
                        <li key={index} className="pb-4 hover:scale-105 duration-300">
                        <NavLink to={`/${layout}${path}${items.innerpath}`}>
                            <button className="text-left text-sm">{items.title}</button>
                        </NavLink>
                          
                        </li>
                      ))}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                )}
```

I think the issue lied with improper mapping over the component.